# How to erase character from a text string

Tags: java, processing

How can i erase character from a text string by pressing the back space key.
This is what i have got so far. It only deletes the last character.

```
if (keyPressed) {
    if (key != '\n' && key != CODED) {
        if (typing.length() < 5){
            typing = typing + key;
        }
    }
    if (key == BACKSPACE) {
        if (typing.length() > 0) {
            typing = typing.substring(0, typing.length()-1);
        }
    }
}

text(typing, 345, 372);
```

Comment: where the String comes from? Are you using GUI?

Comment: put your `key==BACKSPACE` inside the if(keypressed) bolck

Comment: thank you Bhavik Shah. How did i not see that??

Comment: @MadProgrammer.. Doesn't substring take the substring from `startIndex` to `endIndex - 1`? So it should be `typing.length() - 1` only. That part of OP code is correct.

Comment: @MadProgrammer `substring` gives the string which begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. so if one wants to drop the last character only why should we not use `typing = typing.substring(0, typing.length()-1);`

Comment: @RohitJain You are right (always confuses the willies out of me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `BACKSPACE` [is not `CODED`](http://processing.org/reference/key.html), so while `typing.length()` is smaller than `5`and  you press `BACKSPACE` you meet both conditions breaking stuff. When it reaches `5` it only mets second condition: `if (key == BACKSPACE)` so it works, bringing it back to less than `5` so it won't work again...

As a test try:`if (key != '\n' && key != CODED && key != BACKSPACE)`
But i think you might want a `switch (key)` to do the job.

Also you better use `void keyPressed()` or `keyReleased()` or `keyTyped()`
Instead of `keyPressed` the field, in draw(). Or you will need to handle key repetition yourself...

Comment: when i saw Bhavik Shah`s comment i realized what i have done wrong. Thanks for explanation.